# Need tools which will refactor the C# code for null checks

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, null, automated-refactoring

Can anyone suggest me for automating the null check refactoring in C# code? The actual problem is, I have a C# console application with 500 files where in each file contains so main IF-ELSE conditional statement for user-defined objects. Now, I need to put null checks for all the objects(also nested objects) used in these IF-ELSE conditional statements.

To achieve this, I need a tool which will place the null checks automatically.

Comment: Can only some objects me null?  Why are you not handling a null object before you do anything special to it?

Comment: some or all objects may be null as it depends on the runtime data provided. I need to check if the obj is null or not in foreach scenario too.Any ideas how to automate this??

Comment: Do you want a null check on *every* if-then-else? If a null is found, what do you want done?  Please post an example of "before null check installed", and "after null check installed".  Like show what you want done with **for** loops.

Answer (score 3):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) will *help* you find these. Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. another requirement is - to indicate null check for the objects created in FOREACH loop. Forex, foreach(object obj1 in list){ console.writeln(obj1.Name);} In this case, if the obj1 is null then NULLPointer exception will be thrown.Is there any tool similar to Resharp or any feature in Resharp that indicates NULL check for the objects created in FOREACH Statement.